# How would I use regular expression to extract words outside of brackets in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to extract the value outside of brackets from a column.

Query:

```
select dwn_notes from down_time;
```

Query Result:

```
4 hour scheduled downtime (dball, 01/04/2019 09:14)
4 hour scheduled downtime (dball, 01/04/2019 09:14)
4 hour scheduled downtime (dball, 01/04/2019 09:14)
4 hour scheduled downtime (dball, 01/04/2019 09:14)
```

Comment: Is it always everything to the left of the first open paren?  That doesn't require a regex.

Comment: Its could be left or to the right

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, you can just use `instr` to locate the first open paren, and substring that out:

```
select dwn_notes,
substr(dwn_notes,1,instr(dwn_notes,'(') -1)
from
down_time
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de14dd44ffce4e94533f19e53c9ce17a)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to capture the part of the string before the parenthesis in a group and the part after the group, then return just those groups.  Make sure to use a good set of test data, including values you don't expect.

```
with down_time(id, down_notes) as (
  select 1, '1 hour scheduled downtime (dball, 01/04/2019 09:14)' from dual union all
  select 2, '2 hour scheduled downtime (dball, 01/05/2019 09:14) with more text after' from dual union all
  select 3, '' from dual union all
  select 4, '(dball, 01/04/2019 09:14)' from dual union all
  select 5, '5 hour scheduled downtime' from dual
)
select id, trim(regexp_replace(down_notes, '^(.*?)\s*\(.*\)\s*(.*?)$', '\1 \2')) down_notes
from down_time;
```

Be advised that if `REGEXP_REPLACE()` does not find a match, the string passed in will be returned. This is different from `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, where it returns NULL if it can't find a match. You may have to allow for this in returned values.

Comment: This wont be cost efficient as processor will fetch two Regex instead of one, one above mentioned by @Nikhil would be better. Fetch it and replace it with null.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select regexp_replace(down_notes,'[(]{1}(.)*[)]{1}','') from Table1;
```

check  fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b52fd/6

Comment: Regex `\(.*\)` would be easier, isn't it? As the one you mentioned takes about 54 steps and the one I mentioned takes 5 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the part of the string upto the opening parentheses is enough for your case :

```
select regexp_substr(dwn_notes,'([^\()])+') as dwn_notes
  from dwn_time;
```

If you need everything outside of the paretheses, then consider :

```
select concat(
               regexp_substr(dwn_notes,'([^\(.*\))])+'), 
               regexp_substr(dwn_notes,'([^\(.*\))])+$')
              ) as dwn_notes
  from dwn_time;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbda2a23f1d4f3373dd1fbde83869bd7)</kbd>